# How to set id for bootstrap tabs in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am generating tabs and the tab content dynamically using json format.

Here is the code that is generated after passing the json data:

```
<ul  class="nav-tabs>
    <li class = "active">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-tab-id="step3_tab_1" id="SAMPLE"><span class="icon icon-untitled"></span> DEMO</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to set the id of active tab to the below save button which is located under respective tabs.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <button id="" name="demo_save" type="button" class="btn">                               
        <span class="icon-floppy"></span> Save
    </button>
</div>
```

So, whenever a tab is active the save button under the respective active button will get the id of that tab.

How can I implement this???

Answer (score 0):

Code below should work (if I correctly understood You)

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).find('a').data('tab-id');
    $('button').attr('id', id);
})
```

But You can get tab id when You click the button:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var id = $('li.active').find('a').data('tab-id');
    $(this).attr('id', id);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you generate your tab dynamically by javascript, you can add the event listener to the  generated tabs by using following code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul.nav-tabs li', function() {
    var id = $(this).find('a').data('tab-id'); // get respective tab-content's id of the tab
    $('#'+id+'.tab-content button').attr('id', id); // set the id of button in given tab-content
});
```

Comment: am following your fiddle only..am able to get the id of nav-tabs.However, am not able to print that id on tab-content button id.

Comment: I really can't understand what you want.

Comment: what you provided in jsfiddle is what am looking for.. However am not able to set the id of nav-tabs in tab-content